# Global Resource Object in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm just getting into Spring (and Java), and despite quite a bit of research, I can't seem to even express the terminology for what I'm trying to do. I'll just explain the task, and hopefully someone can point me to the right Spring terms.

I'm writing a Spring-WS application that will act as middleware between two APIs. It receives a SOAP request, does some business logic, calls out to an external XML API, and returns a SOAP response. The external API is weird, though. I have to perform "service discovery" (make some API calls to determine the valid endpoints -- a parameter in the XML request) under a variety of situations (more than X hours since last request, more than Y requests since last discovery, etc.).

My thought was that I could have a class/bean/whatever (not sure of best terminology) that could handle all this service discovery stuff in the background. Then, the request handlers can query this "thing" to get a valid endpoint without needing to perform their own discovery and slow down request processing. (Service discovery only needs to be re-performed rarely, so it would be impactful to do it for every request.)

I thought I had found the answer with singleton beans, but every resource says those shouldn't have state and concurrency will be a problem -- both of which kill the idea.

How can I create an instance of "something" that can:

1) Wake up at a defined interval and run a method (i.e. to check if Service discovery needs to be performed after X hours and if so do it).

2) Provide something like a getter method that can return some strings.

3) Provide a way in #2 to execute a method in the background without delaying `return` (basically detect that an instance property exceeds a value and execute -- or I suppose, issue a request to execute -- an instance method).

I have experience with multi-threaded programming, and I have no problem using threads and mutexes. I'm just not sure that's the proper way to go in Spring.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it right but I think that you may be seeking for the Quartz functionality. Not sure though. Take a look: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons ideally shouldn't have state because of multithreading issues. However, it sounds like what you're describing is essentially a periodic query that returns an object describing the results of the discovery mechanism, and you're implementing a cache. Here's what I'd suggest:

- Create an immutable (value) object `MyEndpointDiscoveryResults` to hold the discovery results (e.g., endpoint address(es) or whatever other information is relevant to the SOAP consumers).
- Create a singleton Spring bean `MyEndpointDiscoveryService`.
- On the discovery service, save an `AtomicReference<MyEndpointDiscoveryResults>` (or even just a plain volatile variable). This will ensure that all threads see updated results, while limiting them to a single, atomically updated field containing an immutable object limits the scope of the concurrency interactions.
- Use `@Scheduled` or another mechanism to run the appropriate discovery protocol. When there's an update, construct the entire result object, then save it into the updated field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is the right direction. Could you expand on #1 and #2? For #1, would it be some sort of Spring-based object, or how and where would I define it? Would this immutable object be the AtomicReference<MyEndpointDiscoveryResults>? Would I have access to this object through bean dependency injection or another mechanism? Additionally, I take it that the MyEndpointDisoveryResults should be separated from the For #2, is that a singleton bean, or some other kind of singleton? `@Scheduled` led me to `Runnable` along with `@Async`, which I think will work nicely.

Comment: @fandingo Updated. The results object is just a plain immutable value object. The point of putting all of that into a single object is that it lets you swap out "new results" for "old results" in a single assignment, which ameliorates the threading concerns.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer.